# How to notify DNS address change with code in c++?

Tags: c++, dns

I want to monitor the DNS address change,can I set up an event handler or callback function in my code that is triggered when the DNS address change.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

You would need to periodically poll your DNS server, then do something when the address changed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about DNS specifically, but if you're looking for a way to programatically monitor your own host for network events, the [netlink socket API](http://qos.ittc.ku.edu/netlink/html/index.html) may be of use. A better option may be to utilize the [netplug](http://www.demailly.com/~dl/netplug.html) daemon. Both options assume a unix environment.